# Is Inheritance in Python canonically the same as in other languages? A comparative example with Java

Tags: java, python, oop, inheritance

I have been puzzling today, as (simplified) python code seemed to raise an exception.

Here's the code in python :

```
class AwinBaseOperator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = self.get_data(query_url='test')

    def get_data(self, query_url):
        print('Parent called with ', repr(query_url))

class AwinTransactionOperator(AwinBaseOperator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get_data(self):
        print('Child called')
        
print(AwinTransactionOperator())
```

This returns: `Child called with  'test.'`

It means the code is trying to use the child class's `get_data` within the `AwinBaseOperator` constructor, which should be wrong. So I tried to confirm this behavior isn't normal by translating my code to Java and running it.

Here is the relevant Java code :

I create a project, which is structured as such.

```
--- Project
 |---src
   |---Main.java  // Contains the main function call
   |---Awin
     |---AwinBaseOperator.java
     |---AwinTransactionOperator.java
```

Here are the respective class definitions

```
import Awin.AwinTransactionOperator;


public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AwinTransactionOperator a = new AwinTransactionOperator();
  }
}
```

```
package Awin;


public class AwinBaseOperator{
        
     public AwinBaseOperator(){
         this.getData("test");
     }
     
     public void getData(String query_url){
         System.out.println("Parent called getData with "+query_url);
     }
}
```

```
package Awin;
import Awin.AwinBaseOperator;


public class AwinTransactionOperator extends AwinBaseOperator{
    
    public AwinTransactionOperator(){
        super();
    }
    
    public void getData(){
        System.out.println("Child called getData");
    }
}
```

Which returns `Parent called getData with test.`

1. Could you please explain this fundamental difference in processing the main Object Oriented concept 'inheritance'?
2. What am I missing?

Comment: I think in `python` that classes have all their methods determined before `__init__()` is called. In general, I don't think `method resolution during construction` is defined by the concept of inheritance.

Comment: Your test is invalid, because `AwinTransactionOperator.getData` doesn't override the method in `AwinBaseOperator` - it overloads it. (It has different parameters.) Moreover, it still writes "Parent called getData" when presumably it should write "Child called getData".

Comment: But once it *does* override the method, you'll see the `AwinTransactionOperator` implementation called, not the `AwinBaseOperator` implementation.

Comment: As a side-note, the title of this question is pointlessly provocative. Even if Python and Java behaved differently here, speculating that that would make Python inheritance "broken" is not helpful.

Comment: Alright, all your remarks are noted. Indeed when I give the same signature to the function, the `Child class` method is called. Thanks for clearing up the misunderstanding.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I've done the editing. To conclude this thread: Python doesn't do **overloading**, and my example in Java is not one of **overriding**, but of **overloading**. Would you like to write an answer to resolve this question?

Comment: No, I don't have time now, but it sounds like you can probably answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shown example in **Java** does not display the use of `Overriding`, but that of `Overloading` the `getData` method.

Once we change the signature of `AwinTransactionOperator.getData` to

```
public void getData(String query_url){
        System.out.println("Child called getData with "+query_url);
}
```

The output is `Child called getData with test`.

Python does not support **overloading**.